# How to use external bluetooth (TP-Link) in laptop rather than inbuilt one?

Tags: networking, bluetooth, laptop, devices

I have a TP-Link Bluetooth 5.0 USB that I want to use with my laptop rather than the inbuilt one. I'm using ubuntu 20.04.
I switched from windows to ubuntu and was using TP-link Bluetooth 5.0 rather than the old inbuilt bluetooth of the laptop. On Windows 10 I disabled the inbuild Bluetooth from the device manager.
I cannot find similar functionality in ubuntu. Is it possible to do so in ubuntu? How can I do this?